# How to knit rmd file to create an table with Chi-Squared and p symbols?

Tags: pdflatex, kable, p-value, chi-squared

How to use math symbols of Chi-Squared and P in kable() function in Rmd file?

Following try did not work.

```
colnames(df) <- c("$\chi^2$ ", "$p$")
table_df2 %>%
  kable("latex", booktabs = T,  escape = FALSE, caption = "One-Sample Chi-Squared Test on Variance", digits = 3) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("stripdown","hold_position"), font_size = 6)
```

[image: Expected table]